# Big hat! Is this expected behavior?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I increased the size of hat using the controls, and it <del>not</del> looks great everywhere! Is it a <del>bug</del> feature?

> [image]

<sup>and also it hides the "**recent reviews**" link & non clickable.</sup>

Comment: ...........BIG BUG HAAAAAAAAAAT!!!!

Comment: Seriously, though, you look great. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Not really. Hats are just a "for fun" thing. The fact they're not perfect is irrelevant.

Comment: +1 just for the edit...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hats are magnificent, mysterious, and most of all independent beasts. Who are we to dictate the bounds in which a hat must be confined?

Comment: Are you going to hit the developer that thought this hat was a good idea?

Comment: @PeterJ Don't blame the developers, this wasn't our idea.

Comment: Um, we're the despotic overlords. The _exact_ people who get to dictate... well, everything, including hat boundaries.

Comment: Also mercurial.  Missed that superlative.

Comment: hey thanks I finally found you for hat!!!!

Comment: I like the ability to scale and rotate the hat this year, *a lot*. But yes, it’s up to the user to how to wear their hat, I guess…

Comment: The main thing with the hats, it seems to me, is to wear all the ones you earn at least once, even if it is only for a short time.  Just to show solidarity!  (And get extra hats, of course.)

Comment: There's an overwhelming amount of hats, all of them with their own prerequisites. One of them requires commenting on one of your posts or answers. Thanks for the hat. ;)

Comment: I got a hat from my mom for Christmas, but I can't upload to StackExchange. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8):

While it's not on me to devalue the epic truth in Mrs. Hairboat's realisation that we don't "dictate the bounds in which a hat must be confined", let me put it this way: Yeah we do.

You cannot go too wild with placing & sizing the hat. But a certain amount is allowed, and I don't see a problem with your screenshot. In particular, all "recent reviews" links look at least partially clickable, so it shouldn't be causing issues. In some places we do shift content around if the hat would cover it otherwise, but right here it seems fine.